# MySQL Error : 3161 Laravel can not create temporary tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The case is I am deploying Laravel on a new server, first I pull all Laravel files from my Repo, then import the database and linked them together, while I am testing the website after running I found this error..

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3161 Storage engine MEMORY is disabled (Table creation is disallowed).

When I check my database Engine it used InnoDB, Also when run show engines; command it shows that MEMORY has value YES which mean it runs.

Some resources say but I am not sure of that, This problem appears on the cloud servers.

My trials:

change the user permissions.
change mysql version to an older one. (5.7.3)
try to force MEMORY to be the engine from the .sql file.